# How to exclude date in RRule.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-6, rrule

**Suspected code:**

```
<script src="https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/dist/es5/rrule.min.js"></script>
// Create a rule:
        const rule = new rrule.RRule({
            freq: rrule.RRule.DAILY,
            dtstart: new Date('{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($product->details->date_from . ' -1 day'))}}'),
            until: new Date('{{$product->details->date_to_1 ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($product->details->date_to_1 . ' +1 day'))  : date('Y-m-d', strtotime($product->details->date_to . ' +1 day'))}}'),
        });

        rule.exdate(new Date("2020-06-25"));
```

**Console got that:**

```
TypeError: rule.exdate is not a function
```

But if we follow the official guide [RRule repo manual](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule)

**We can observe the solution as :)**

> ```
> // Add a exclusion date to rruleSet
> rruleSet.exdate(new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 5, 1, 10, 30)))
> ```

I'm unable to figured it out where am i wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
**Aizaz**

Answer (score 2):

```
const rruleSet = new RRuleSet();
rruleSet.rrule(
  new RRule({
    freq: RRule.DAILY,
    count: 5,
    dtstart: new Date("Aug 2020 10 10:30 am"),
  })
);
rruleSet.exdate(new Date("Aug 2020 12 10:30 am"));
```

Here, it will exclude 12th Aug and gives back (10,11,13,14 of Aug).

Answer (score 2):

RRuleSet is a different object to RRule. You will find exdate on the RRuleSet object and not on the RRule.

1. Create a RRuleSet
2. Add add your RRule
3. Add your exclusion on the RRuleSet

Answer (score 1):

The `EXDATE` prop will only work in `RRuleSet`. So, after including `rrule.js` script, you can exclude a single date or multiple dates like this:

```
const RRuleSet = rrule.RRuleSet;
const rruleSet = new RRuleSet();

rruleSet.rrule(
  new RRule({
    freq: RRule.DAILY,
    count: 5,
    dtstart: new Date("2022-04-15"),
  })
);

rruleSet.exdate(new Date("2022-04-25"));

// Again add 'exdate()' to exclude another date
rruleSet.exdate(new Date("2022-04-28"));
```

After that, convert `rruleSet` into string using `toString()`

```
let rruleStr = rruleSet.toString();
```

So, to check recurrence you should first convert `rruleStr` string to object using `rrulestr()` and than iterate rule using `all()`, `before()`, `after()` or `between()` retrival methods:

```
let ruleSetObj = rrule.rrulestr(rruleStr);
let ruleNextOccurrence = ruleSetObj.after(new Date('2022-04-25'), true);
```